# Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaConventions

Tags: eclipse

I'm getting the message written in the title when I start eclipse. Besides I keep getting the message 'Building workspace has encountered a problem'.

Recently I updated Java from 7 to 8, so this may be a problem source but I'm not sure. I also installed Spring using the 'eclipse marketplace'.

First time I got this problem I updated eclipse Mars.1 to Mars.2 and got rid of this error message...but only for a few hours. After rebooting my PC I got the same error messages again and here I am now.

Is there any other way than reinstalling eclipse? All these plugins like Spring IDE take long time to install so I want to avoid reinstalling somehow.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, 
I'm facing the same issue.
If I find the sollution , I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Hi man basically what the error tells you is because your Java not doing propery, what i've done is

1. First of all i installed Java 8 on my computer and then i download java 7
2. On my eclipse i change java compiler from 8 to 7
3. and the last i change the jre using jre 7

hope that help you out

regards