# Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaConventions - Eclipse Neon 3

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I am currently using Eclipse Neon 3 with Spring Tool suites installed. Everything worked fine, till these error messages popped up, and I can't work on my projects in my workspace anymore.

Error message:

```
"Loading Spring static imports into Eclipse code assist favourites".
```

org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/parser/Scanner (wrong name: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/parser/Scanner$AjcClosure1)

Thank you.

Edit: I am getting this error message as well:

```
"Loading Spring static imports into Eclipse code assist favourites".
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/parser/Scanner (wrong name: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/parser/Scanner$AjcClosure1)
```

Comment: possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903790/could-not-initialize-class-org-eclipse-jdt-core-javaconventions

Comment: My guess would be, you might have been using older version of eclipse pointing to the same ws. As a work around, you can take backup of all your project folders, delete `.metadata`, `.recommenders` and `RemoteSystemsTempFiles` folders from your work space and restart eclipse in this ws again.

Comment: That solution did not work, so that's why I reasked the question.

Comment: @ShyamBaitmangalkar I tried switching workspaces, and deleting the `.metadeta` and `RemoteSystemsTempFiles`, but the same error still persists.